# Highcharts not displaying column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying for the past several hours to get my Highcharts loaded.

Everything seems to be correct. I have Jquery before the Highcharts reference.

I have no errors on my console within Chrome.

I'd like it to look like this (working JQuery)
[Working Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/TangoAlee/66ou8znd/)

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <title>Tool Tracker</title>        

<body>
    <div>

<div id="chart_id" class="chart" style="height:100px; width:100%"></div>

    </div>


<!-- Maps the Python template context variables from views.py to the Highchart js variables -->
<script>
var chart_id = chart_id
var chart = {'renderTo': 'chart_id', 'height': 500}
var title = {'text': '123456 Tool life by Location'}
var xAxis = {'categories': ['T01', 'T02']}
var series = [{'data': [211, 550], 'type': 'column', 'name': 'Average'}]
</script>

<!-- Highchart js. Variable map shown above -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(chart_id).highcharts({
        chart: chart,
        title: title,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        series: series
    });
});
 </script>

</body>
```

**Below is a JSfiddle - [Not working](https://jsfiddle.net/TangoAlee/a4cbycp2/7/)**

THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: Use '#' for jQuery selector. So change var chart_id = chart_id to var chart_id = '#chart_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not working fiddle has 2 problems:

First, all the scripts are included 2 times, both in the html part and in the `External resource` tool of JSfiddle. You need to either remove the external resources or remove the `<script>` tags.

Second, in the first line of your javascript `var chart_id = 'chart_id` you missed the closing `';` and the `#` before the chart_id to let JQuery know it's an ID you are refering to.

`var chart_id = '#chart_id';` Is what you want.

[Working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4cbycp2/8/)

Comment: something so simple has kept me up basically all night! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

HTML code from original sample:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript code with your data:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: '123456 Tool life by Location'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['T01', 'T02']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'Some text',
                style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{'data': [211, 550], 'type': 'column', 'name': 'Average'}]
    });
});
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/logual/9gpw688e/1/

[image]